# InDesign relink - same files (size, extension), but different name

Tags: adobe-indesign

I was given an InDesign file with links that are in Korean language.
The original file names mostly use Korean symbols, but the files I have were all renamed. Here is an example:

> %#@$.psd 
>   (please understand the #%#$ as Korean symbols, the website does not allow me to use them in the body)

- original file name. Thats how I see it in the links panel in InDesign

> _____.psd

- that is how the files were somehow automatically renamed **before** I got them.

So, all symbols in Korean are replaced with a "_".
Files are the same size and extension, but are not recognized because of the name.

Is there some trick to do it faster than 1 by 1. Doing them 1 by 1, I have just the file size as reference and it will take ages (200+ links).

Comment: Hello @Alex747, if I understand correctly, InDesign is using the file names and this is an Operating System issue? We're not tech specialists, so I'm not too confident we're going to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with an automated script. You must point it to the right folder to read the images from, the rest can be done automatically.

InDesign stores not only the name of linked files into your document, but also lots more – see the JavaScript Reference for [Link](http://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign11/#Link.html) for a full list. Since `size` is among these, this script can locate candidates, and automatically replace it if there is only one. For safety measures, it checks if the file has the same file extension as well (and for this to work, it ignores case differences). The file is *only* replaced when there is exactly *one* candidate, so check the Linked Files list after running for left-overs.

The script first asks from which folder it should read the images from; the default is the folder containing the InDesign document, but you can navigate elsewhere as well.

The following is a JavaScript, so save as `findLostImages.jsx` into your User Scripts folder. Then run it by double-clicking in your Scripts panel.

Run this **on a saved copy** of your original InDesign document. Due to the specific nature of this request, I could not thoroughly test it, and so if things go awry you'll be happy to have a backup.

```
//DESCRIPTION:Find lost images by size
// A Rad Lexus Script 31-Jul-2016

if (!app.documents.length)
{
    alert ('please open a document first');
    exit();
}

problems = [];

path = Folder(app.activeDocument.filePath).selectDlg("Select file source");
if (path)
{
    // load the images in this folder
    filelist = path.getFiles ('*.*');
//  alert (filelist);

    // loop over the images
    for (i=0; i<app.activeDocument.allGraphics.length; i++)
    {
        // is it a linked file?
        if (app.activeDocument.allGraphics[i].itemLink &&
            app.activeDocument.allGraphics[i].itemLink.needed)
        {
            size = app.activeDocument.allGraphics[i].itemLink.size;
            extension = app.activeDocument.allGraphics[i].itemLink.filePath.substring
                (app.activeDocument.allGraphics[i].itemLink.filePath.lastIndexOf('.')).toLowerCase();
            // check our list
            matches = [];
            for (j=0; j<filelist.length; j++)
            {
                // extension the same?
                if (extension.localeCompare(filelist[j].fullName.substring
                    (filelist[j].fullName.lastIndexOf('.')).toLowerCase()) == 0)
                {
                    // size the same?
                    if (filelist[j].length == size)
                        matches.push (filelist[j]);
                }
            }
            // did we find a match?
            if (matches.length == 1)
            {
                app.activeDocument.allGraphics[i].itemLink.relink (matches[0]);
            } else
            {
                if (matches.length == 0)
                    problems.push ('no match for '+app.activeDocument.allGraphics[i].itemLink.filePath);
                else
                    problems.push ('multiple matches for '+app.activeDocument.allGraphics[i].itemLink.filePath);
            }
        }
    }
    if (problems.length)
        alert (problems.join('\r'), 'Problems');
}
```