# Strange image filenames from publisher

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have an issue I've been struggling with for a long time.

I work as a graphical designer for a publisher in Norway. We basically buy licenses from (primarily) UK publishers like Future Publishing, Carlton, Lonely Planet etc, translate them then release them in Norway.

When downloading the source files, they obviously create a lot of missing links in ID. We've found a solution as to finding them easily because the filenames match. However, primarily with Future we have a problem.

There seems to be some sort of identification or index number in front of the file names, followed by an '@' sign – THEN the file name (see picture for further explanation).

This is only the case with the downloaded image files. The links in ID still have the "original" file name. That leaves me no choice but to *manually* go through and relink 600-800 pictures per edition.

Of course I could just go through the filenames and delete everything in front of the '@' sign, but another issue arises. For some images with long filenames, the last characters seems to be missing. Perhaps because the file name was too long.

Does anything know if there is something to do about this, or should I contact Future directly?

Thanks!

[image: How it looks in Finder.]

Comment: sounds like a manual thing on Future's end. Contact them and ask what's up. I'm not aware of anything in ID which would arbitrarily add an index number to linked image files.

Comment: Fixing the names to cut at  the @ sign is easy to automate though.

Comment: @joojaa True, but the OP notes that `"For some images with long filenames, the last characters seems to be missing."` Removing everything up to @ is okay, but doesn't solve the entire problem. The next batch of images could all be truncated names, and would still have to be manually relinked.

Comment: If you're paying for these licences, presumably they should deliver something you can work with, so better just ask the publishers to deliver working packages?

Comment: @Lucian I will most definitely do that, but unfortunately in the printing industry, you don't always get what you need to start working on it.. Some don't attach fonts, you cannot use all pictures they sent due to copyright and so on.. But I guess I will need to contact them then.. Thanks for answers! :)

Comment: Could the script I wrote for a [similar question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/75489/30216) be of help? It can find the original files and relink them; no need for renaming. (The chance of 2 image files having the same size is quite small.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a PC, there is a great piece of freeware called [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) that can help you quickly strip everything up to and including the @.  Doesn't solve the problems with the missing end characters, but can make removing the characters at the beginning quick and easy.

Once you have stripped the beginning symbols, then you can place all of the images in a single folder and make sure that the setting to "Check folder for Missing Links" is set when you relink one of the images.  That will automatically update all of the other links that are not missing characters.

But, I would definitely contact Future--there may be a simple setting that they can tweak to make sure the images are exported during packaging with their original file names.